# Identificar los ultimos caracteres de un string con criteriabuilder

Tags: javascript, java, sql, lógica, criteria

Tengo una tabla que esta llena de codigos todos con una longitud de 8 caracteres, Mi pregunta es con criteriabuilder o SQl hay alguna manera de retornar solo los codigos que tengan en sus ultimos dos caracteres 00.

Gracias por la atencion y la ayuda

Comment: Puedes usar [SUBSTRING()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) o simplemente `LIKE columna '%00'`. Por cierto, ¿qué tiene que ver esto con Javascript?

Comment: Hay varias maneras . Por ejemplo léelo a una lista y después usar el Stream para sacar los últimos.

Comment: @Triby lo siento por colocar lo de javascript por cierto gracias no conocia lo del substring :D